# A supposed contradiction of a compact set in infinite dimensional Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, compactness

Let $X$ be a infinite dimensional Banach space. We learned in class that $$1. \dim(X)=\infty \iff \text{Bolzano-Weierstrass property does not hold}$$

Now I have the following definition for compactness of a subset $A$:
$$2. \text{ Every sequence } \{x_j\}^{\infty}_{j=1} \text{in } A \text{ has accumulation point in } A$$

My confusion lies in that wouldn't this mean that there exists no infinite dimensional compact Banach space (which is not true)?

Because if X is Banach and infinite dimensional and compact $\xrightarrow{2.}$ every sequence (so in particular also bounded sequences) have an accumulation point in A. But having an accumulation point means, there exists a subsequence converging to the accumulation point, thus BW holds which contradicts 1.?

Comment: 1) is wrong...$\ \ $

Comment: A normed space $\ne\{0\}$ cannot be compact.(Compact sets are bounded, linear subspaces $\ne\{0\}$ are clearly unbounded)

Comment: @daw but isn't the Hilbert cube compact,  $\neq \{0\}$? Am I understanding you correctly that you want to point out that this part of my question "there exists no infinite dimensional compact Banach space (which is not true)?" might not be correct?

Comment: .. it is not a vector space...

Comment: @daw Ah yes, my fault, I somehow equated Banach with complete metric space. But then do I gather correctly that there is no problem with the contradiction, I just verified very complicatedly why a normed vector space not $\{0\}$ is never compact?

Comment: No normed linear space $\ne 0$ has the Bolzano-Weierstrass property . Do you perhaps mean the closed unit ball has (or does not have) the Bolzano-Weierstrass property?

Comment: I'm not sure whether I use the wrong terminology, is there a difference between the BW property and theorem? I mean, that every bounded sequence has convergent subsequence. And this holds obviously for at least $\mathbb{R} $, which is a normed linear space